# Solr implement custom scoring function

Tags: solr

I'm trying to implement my own custom scoring function with Solr - I want Solr to do a KNearestNeighbor and return the closest result with the highest score.

I've been following these two implementations [external-score-to-solr](http://spykem.blogspot.pt/2013/06/plug-in-external-score-to-solr.html) and [using-custom-score-query](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/03/12/using-customscorequery-for-custom-solrlucene-scoring/).

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR**

On my schema, I have the following field:

```
<field name="histogram" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

An example of a document with a **histogram** field data would be:

```
"bin1|1.23 bin2|-0.24 bin3|-1.89 bin4|5.21"
```

Following the two links above, I've end up extendind the **CustomScoreProvider** class, and my **customScore** function is:

```
@Override
public float customScore(int doc, float subQueryScore, float valSrcScores[]) throws IOException {

    Document d = context.reader().document(doc);
    String histogram = d.get("histogram");

    // Here I have a function that splits the string by space and then parse
    // each name and value
    Map<<String, Float> histogramMap = getDocumentHistogram(histogram);

    // A similar function but for the query terms. Can be done only once
    // query is the type of org.apache.lucene.search.Query
    Map<<String, Float> queryMap = getQueryHistogram(query.toString());

    // Trivial function to compute KNN
    float score = computeScore(histogramMap, queryMap);

    return 1/score;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

What I've done works, but as you can see in the implementation has a bad performance, because for each query I need to parse the features before computing the score. I can parse the query terms only once, but I still need to parse the histogram of every single document to be able to compute the score.

So, is there a way of getting a List / Array / Map / etc of my **histogram** features already parsed in the **customScore** function ? This field type is **payload**, which uses the **WhitespaceTokenizerFactory** tokenizer with the **pipe** as a delimiter, so there should be a way of solr return each individual terms.

I can provide more details of what I've done, and I'm using Solr 6.0.1.

Thanks, 
Sérgio

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Parse histogram when you will index your document and add it to the index.
And you will be able to use indexed field during ranking.